# Why am I always getting 0 always after running my c program? Kindly help me out

Tags: c, initialization, arguments, function-definition

```
     #include<stdio.h>
     #include<math.h>

     float distance(float a,float b,float c,float d);


      int main()

      {
    float x1,y1,x2,y2,dist;
    printf("Input x1: ");
    scanf("%f", &x1);
     printf("Input y1: ");
      scanf("%f", &y1);
          printf("Input x2: ");
      scanf("%f", &x2);
       printf("Input y2: ");
      scanf("%f", &y2);
       distance(x1,x2,y1,y2);
      printf("Distance between the given points is: %.2f",sqrt(dist));

     return 0;
      }
    float distance(float a,float b,float c,float d)
   {
    float x1,x2,y1,y2,dist;
   dist=((x2-x1)*(x2-x1) +(y2-y1)*(y2-y1));
  return dist;
    }
```

Here the output is always 0, don't know why. I have tried putting float and integers still getting 0.

IGNORE THIS PART OF QUESTION.
WRITING THIS TO SATISFY THE CRITERIA TO POST.

Comment: You are not using the return value of the call distance(x1,x2,y1,y2);. So the variable dist is uninitialized.

Comment: Also these local function variables float x1,x2,y1,y2,dist; are uninitialized. The function does not use its arguments.

Comment: See my answer to the question.

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? Please add more details to the question, and do not try to fiddle around the post criteria

Comment: Thank you guys....understood the mistake and solved the issue.                         
 @Vlad from Moscow   and  The night hunter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
`x1,x2,y1,y2` and `dist` not initialized that was the problem :)

#include<stdio.h>
         #include<math.h>
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
    
         float distance(float a,float b,float c,float d);
    
    
          int main()
    
          {
        float x1,y1,x2,y2,dist;
        printf("Input x1: ");
        scanf("%f", &x1);
         printf("Input y1: ");
          scanf("%f", &y1);
              printf("Input x2: ");
          scanf("%f", &x2);
           printf("Input y2: ");
          scanf("%f", &y2);
           dist=distance(x1,x2,y1,y2);//you didn't put the value of the func into a variable
          printf("Distance between the given points is: %.2f",sqrt(dist));
    
         return 0;
          }
        float distance(float a,float b,float c,float d)//since we already give a,b,c,d a value from calling the func in main
       {
        float dist;
       dist=((b-a)*(b-a) +(d-c)*(d-c));//we just swapped you x1,x2,y1,y2 to the a,b,c,d 
      return dist;
        }
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Comment: And if you want upvotes, spend the time to make the indentation and formatting consistent.  And address error checking - how do you know if those `scanf()` calls actually read something?

Comment: @Nico Haase, I used the variables at the function definition which were meant to be used when the function was to be called that is (x1,x2,y1,y2).   For function definition, I had to use general uninitialized variables that were a,b,c,d. Hope u understood :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the return value of the function call

```
distance(x1,x2,y1,y2);
```

That is you need to write

```
dist = distance(x1,x2,y1,y2);
```

Otherwise the variable `dist` will be still uninitialized and using it in this statement

```
printf("Distance between the given points is: %.2f",sqrt(dist));
```

results in undefined behavior.

The function `distance` does not use its arguments `a`, `b`, `c`, `d`. Instead it uses its uninitialized local variables `x1`, `x2`, `y1`, `y2`

```
    float distance(float a,float b,float c,float d)
   {
    float x1,x2,y1,y2,dist;
   dist=((x2-x1)*(x2-x1) +(y2-y1)*(y2-y1));
  return dist;
    }
```

Write the function at least like

```
    float distance( float a, float b, float c, float d )
    {
        return ( b - a ) * ( b - a ) + ( d - c ) * ( d - c );
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

change your function(it does not use its arguments) to :

```
  '''float distance(float a,float b,float c,float d)
   {
    float dist;
   dist=((a-b)*(a-b) +(c-d)*(c-d));
  return dist;
    }'''
```

and in your code :

```
  printf("Distance between the given points is: %.2f",sqrt(distance(x1,x2,y1,y2)));
```